# can't get data from model binding with a listbox that represents a child table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been my head against this for most of the day. I don't think I understand enough of the moving pieces in MVC and I need some help getting to a solution regarding listboxes and data binding.

Essentially, I want to use a modal dialog to select for a grid of data, and then have the selection show up in a listbox. (that works). I then want to POST that list box to the controller and have child records for each item that was in the list box (doesn't work).

How can I get all the 's from a  elegantly in MVC and get them into the database?

**[Setup]**

I have an object, WorkOrder, that represents a table in SQL. 
WorkOrder has a collection, WorkerRequests, that represents a child table. WorkOrder is the parent.

I have a form that creates new WorkOrders and allows the addition of WorkerRequests through a modal dialog. WorkerRequest records are shown in a listbox after selected with the dialog.

The dialog uses javascript's HTMLOptionsCollection add(Element) function to add an  element. That works.

When I post, the data binder is tossing the added element. I can't seem to find the raw data in the HttpContext, and the binder isn't making it available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listbox items if not selected will not be posted over. You ideally would need them selected OR create them in a hidden form that gets posted to your controller method.

Include a parameter in your action method named

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormsCollection collection )
{
    var item = collection["whateverName"];
}
```

See if it shows up there as a starting point.
Its hard to see exactly whats going on without your code here.

Your model dialog does what - adds to the listbox? Does your dialog post back to your controller to create the dialog? Are your dialog contents inside a form? If you use jQuery's dialog and your dialog is inside a form be aware jQuery will actually pop it outside of your form when it shows your dialog , you have to add it back to your form again. If this is a case for you, I'll update with those details but lets make sure that is/is not whats happening here.